# Windows print spooler not sending job to printer once back online

Tags: windows, printing, zebra-printer

We have 7 mobile printers Zebra ZQ620's that print jobs from a head office enviroment.

When one of these devices go flat when a user is trying to print a job it will cause the current print job to never be sent even after the device comes back online. We could have 10 pending jobs on that printer and once the first one is cleared the other 9 will continue to print as normal.

Should the windows print spooler not be peridodiclly trying to send or is there a better resolution to this?

[image]